# Python Tkinter does not disconnect from X-Server

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm writing an application using Python/Tkinter which must periodically kill the GUI component completely and disconnect from the X-Server in order to complete some operations.  Later after the operation is complete, the GUI is rebuilt.  What I have found is that the destroy() method of my main window appears to kill the GUI (it no longer shows up in the window manager client list), but does not completely close the connection to the X-Server.

I can see an open file descriptor which is a socket and I'm pretty sure is the communication channel to the X-Server (it shows up just after I create my first window).  This open socket is a deal breaker.  While I suppose I could just close the socket, I fear there is more housekeeping that should be done to properly close the connection to the X-Server so it can later be restarted.  Is there a more "complete" way to shut down a Tkinter GUI?  Any thoughts?

Comment: This seems very much so like an overkill. I recommend you think about another solution and/or say why it's absolutely necessary to actually kill the socket every time.